# Android: How can I tell if clicked gallery item is the center one?

Tags: android, gallery

I would like to display the gallery item the user clicked on in full screen, however, only if it is the item in the center.
If the clicked item is not in the center I would want it just to be centered.
Any idea how to distinguish the item which is currently in the center from all other items?

Thanks, Rob

Comment: Are you talking about the Gallery view/widget ? You can get that via getSelectedItemPosition() or getSelectedItem()

Comment: Thanks Mathias, that is exactly what I'm looking for. Please post your comment as an answer so I can credit you with it.

Answer (score 0):

getSelectedItemPosition() on the Gallery object should work.